# How to keep aspect ratio of of circles in table layout in Android

Tags: java, android

I am constucting a grid of 5x6 circles in Java Android.
I am using drawable shape: oval, with equal height and width to create the circles, however they end up as an oval.

Image of oval shapes, instead of circles
[image: Image of oval shapes, instead of circles]

How can I ensure that they will remain as circle?

circle_blue.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#637bfe"/>
            <stroke android:color="#FFFFFF" android:width="5dp"/>
            <!-- Set the same value for both width and height to get a circular shape -->
            <size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In the following the xml I use to construct the grid. I am using a FrameLayout to define the aspect ratio and then a table layout to put the circles into a structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="at.react.reaction.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Instruction"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,5:6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">



    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn25"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn34"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn35"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn41"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn42"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn43"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn44"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn45"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn51"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn52"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn53"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn54"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn55"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn61"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn62"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn63"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn64"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn65"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
                android:elevation="9dp"

                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Use image button "ImageButton" It has the property of aspect ratio which will result in maintaing proper shape

Comment: Not 100% sure this is the issue, but you're combining `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` with top/bottom/start/end constraints. Try removing the `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` constraint to make sure the aspect ratio constraint is taking priority when calculating the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Killer!

Using ImageButton instead of Button solved the issue!

Answer (score -1):

try  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` use other values if that didn't work.

Comment: You are suggesting the OP use a property that does not exist for a `Button` view. I suspect that is one of the reasons someone down voted your answer.

Comment: yea didn't mention he is talking about button :|     probably better to use `Image Button`